# Kriyat haTorah helper materials

Tags: grammar-dikduk, torah-reading, pentateuch-chumash, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, parashat-tazria

I'm looking for a resource where I could find notes for my Bar Mitzvah parsha (Tazria) along the lines of:

- in 4th it's always "hee" and never "huu"
- it's always noga in the middle of the end of the pasuk, otherwise, it's always nega
- it's bo-oyr except when followed by smichut and either ve-oyr or be-oyr otherwise

I occasionally discover these patterns myself and they boost my learning significantly.

Surely, someone must have written these down for the whole Chumash by now?

I mostly care about "tricky" words with multiple vocalisations throughout the reading but any patterns that can help me internalise anything about reading the parasha would be great to discover too.

Comment: You should learn Hebrew grammar, and you'd get 97% percent of it.

Comment: Finding the patterns yourself is generally much more effective as a memory tool.

Comment: I live in Israel and speak more or less fluent Hebrew, in any case, my grammar knowledge is pretty comprehensive, which is why I even discovered the smichut pattern at all. I don't see how knowing grammar could possibly help me see links between cancellations and nikud though.

Comment: @DoubleAA, sure, I could definitely do this myself but a) it takes time I could use otherwise b) I might not find everything c) ideally I'm hoping to find a comprehensive cheatsheet that will highlight and the he's an the hu's as well as all the other intricacies that I could just print and glance at between aliyos

Comment: ideally one that will also make certain unobvious trope marks more prominent, e.g. darga-tvir often comes up for "vehisgir hacohen" but there is one time when it the darga is on "Cohen" and tvir on the word that follows. It's easy to get this bit wrong so it'd be nice for this to be highlighted etc.

Comment: also, regarding grammar I'd love to know how to identify "es" vs "eys" but I haven't seen any explanations re this; also "poseso" vs "pososo" for example, lot's of these bits

Comment: @rudolfovic I've made cheat sheets divided into sections per aliyah and looked at them in between.  It's generally only useful to have a maximum of 3 items per aliyah or you forget them.

Comment: Et with tzere if there is a note on the word, otherwise segol.

Comment: @JoelK what counts as a note? technically each word comes with an annotation. I see there is a tzere with a merkha which is probably the least noty note that there is

Comment: Nikkud and teamim are often related. I suspect your grammar isn't as comprehensive as you think. Fluent speaking is not the same as knowing the underlying grammar.

Comment: @rudolfovic an et without a note at all, i.e. it’s connected to the next word with a makaf. In that case it takes a segol. Otherwise tzere.

Comment: Yeah my Biblical Hebrew grammar is definitely not comprehensive. Can you point to any resources?

Comment: @JoelK does the prefixed et have any distinct semantic meaning? Meaning, in an unmarked sentence could you ever guess whether the et sticks to the word or stands as a separate word?

Answer (score 3):

The Simanin Tikkun (published by Feldheim) has many notes like this in a section they call Shitah Mekubetzet.