Mispronouncing a Sh'wa
Based on the answer to the post on the nature of the Sh'wa, there is a dikduk question regarding modern reading of the Torah. Would exchanging the sh'wa na' (mobile) and sh'wa nach (quiescent) be considered an error that requires repetition of the word? Are there cases where the meaning of the word changes?

There might be cases where the meaning changes, but AFAIK there are always attendant changes. For example, יראו /yir-ʔū/ vs ייראו /yī-rə-ʔū/ for some people only differ in the שווא, but some people differentiate between short and long /i/ sounds.

@magicker72 good example.

So, considering the example of @magicker72 , be careful with 'וַיִּירְאוּ הָעָם אֶת ה, because if you omit the shewa na you say ח"ח see and not fear.

@Kazibácsi such an example can start a table of words which can easily be mispronounced. Many gabaim are not proficient in the dikduk, so practically speaking what could be a good solution: repeat even every mispronounced sh'wa, or append a tikkun with the table, etc.?

Those people shouldn't correct the Torah reader, who are not familiar with the grammar. The Orach Chayim 142:1 is clear: only correct vowel errors if it changes the meaning of the text, and there are such lists available, which collect such tricky words for each parashah.

Sometimes it takes me 10 seconds or so to work out if a trop mistake changes the meaning of the sentence.  By that time he could be 2 pesukim later.  I haven't figured out how to handle that.

@Kazibácsi where can one find such lists? Here? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/140951/kriyat-hatorah-helper-materials

Personally, I receive the newsletter of a certain Eliyahu Levin. I suppose it's a good one, check it out and consider subscribing: https://groups.google.com/g/eliyahule
